# PayPal REST setup is too advanced for my users, is there an alternative?

Tags: php, rest, soap, paypal

I'm building a site on which I'll provide users with their own webshop.

The webshops need to be able to accept payments, and I've made the integration using PayPal's express checkout (Client-side REST).

I thought all was well, up until the point where I was writing the setup guide for my users.

In order for them to create REST credentials, they need to log into the developer portion of PayPal, create a sandbox account, and then create an app.

Compare that to how it was/is when using NVP/SOAP, where you log into your PayPal Business account, and basically just follow the flow to get your API credentials.

Furthermore the NVP/SOAP implementation of Express Checkout is deprecated, so I'd really like to avoid that implementation, if possible.

I feel like my options boil down to this:

Use REST and force my users to go through a somewhat confusing setup process.

OR

Use NVP/SOAP, which is deprecated, but has a much more streamlined setup process.

**Am I missing something, or is this just how it is?**

**EDIT/UPDATE**

I also reached out to PayPal support and received the following answer:

> There is no other method to obtain REST API credentials other than logging into PayPal Developer and creating a REST application.
>
> The only other 'method' available, would be to use Braintree Payments instead, which provides PayPal integration.
>
> https://www.braintreepayments.com/en-dk?locale=en-dk

So all in all, there doesn't seem to be an "easy" way to get REST credentials

I'll accept the answer by neuromatter, as he is correct, it's always better to use non-deprecated APIs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with REST. When you're developing something new you should always avoid using something already deprecated. Usually large organizations will tell you if they plan to completely turn something off (and perhaps SOAP is too big for PayPal to end anytime soon) but you don't want to take that risk. Even worse than forcing your users to setup REST would be to force your users to setup SOAP then have to setup REST shortly thereafter because they ended support.

For context, have a look at the PayPal setup page for WooCommerce:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/paypal-standard/

As you can see they fully expect people to enter in credentials to configure their store. The only way around this really is if you wanted to offer a more full service product where for a fee you (or someone you employ) would be able to configure their store for them. But that's a separate discussion.